# Post on a Chatter feed on VisualForce page has died overnight

Tags: visualforce, chatter

I redirect users from std Account page to a VF page.
the tab featuring

```
<apex:outputPanel > <chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!Account.id}"/> </apex:outputPanel>
```

no longer works - users cannot post into the Chatter. 
Triggers for logged activities can still push to the account.
The Enter a Meeting (New Event) publisher Action still works ok.
The issue is also newly present in Sandbox.
If I revert to default Account pages Chatter works ok (but obviously we don't want this).

Same issue in any browser so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Some users can still post - I can too, if I log in as them.
If I log in as someone who can't - I can't.

Comment: Do any errors get displayed to the users who can't post?

Comment: No errors. Just non function. One user - same profile as another user who can post - noted issues with the 'File' option on the Account's chatter section. My File works fine.

Comment: I have SF support on this one. THey actually responded quickly. I will share updates.

Comment: It appears anyone who has access to some report Charts on the Account page is having the error. Anyone else have exp with this?

Answer (score 2):

Check your setup audit trail (Setup->Security Controls->View Setup Audit Trail).

It's likely some permissions or sharing settings changed on the Account object or the related Visualforce page / Apex class.